# bash - nested EOF

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I´m trying to create a file using

```
cat - << EOF > file.sh
```

But inside this, I want to write another EOF. Its hard to explain, so here an example:

```
cat - << EOF > file1.sh
echo first
cat - << EOF > file2.sh
echo second
EOF
echo again first
EOF
```

But of course, at line 5 it breaks. It does not create file1.sh with the content line 2-6, but with the content line 2-4.

Comment: Just use different delimiter strings; they don't have to be "`EOF`".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use a different delimiter on the outer cat, "EOF" isn't special in any way to the shell:

```
cat - << REALEND > file1.sh
echo first
cat - << EOF > file2.sh
echo second
EOF
echo again first
REALEND
```

Results in this content in `file1.sh`

```
echo first
cat - << EOF > file2.sh
echo second
EOF
echo again first
```